# Swift mailer Symfony2 error

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Using Symfony2, I don't get to configure correctly the mailer for sending e-mails.

My configuration is this:

```
mailer_transport="gmail"
mailer_host="gmail"
mailer_user="********"
mailer_password="*******"
```

The error I get is this:

```
Swift_TransportException: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "pgbonino" using 1 possible authenticators
```

Any clue?

Sorry, I didn't say all of it. It works well with a normal Gmail account. It doesn't work with a Google Apps email account. Is there any difference to set in the configuration for this kind of account?

Thanks again

Comment: Are you sure the password is correct? Try to log in to gmail with this same user and password and see if it works

Comment: I usually have mailer_host = localhost and the mailer_user contains the full email address ie someone@someplace.com.  Seems to work fine with a google app account.

Comment: Thanks... I will try that as soon as I get home and tell you how it works

Answer (score 1):

i'm using this config currently for gmail

```
parameters.ini

  mailer_transport:  smtp
  mailer_host:       smtp.gmail.com:465
  mailer_user:       usenrame
  mailer_password:   ***
```